How to solve this error with a parser from this extract of source code?
I'm getting an error as %tb full traceback:
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f0865fee28b7> in <module>
    127     parser.add_argument('out_date', help='outbound date')
    128     parser.add_argument('in_date', help='inbound date')
--> 129     args = parser.parse_args()
    130     outcity = args.outcity
    131     incity = args.incity

C:\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in parse_args(self, args, namespace)
   1766     # =====================================
   1767     def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
-> 1768         args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
   1769         if argv:
   1770             msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in parse_known_args(self, args, namespace)
   1798         # parse the arguments and exit if there are any errors
   1799         try:
-> 1800             namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
   1801             if hasattr(namespace, _UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR):
   1802                 args.extend(getattr(namespace, _UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR))

C:\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in _parse_known_args(self, arg_strings, namespace)
   2032 
   2033         if required_actions:
-> 2034             self.error(_('the following arguments are required: %s') %
   2035                        ', '.join(required_actions))
   2036 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in error(self, message)
   2519         self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
   2520         args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
-> 2521         self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in exit(self, status, message)
   2506         if message:
   2507             self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
-> 2508         _sys.exit(status)
   2509 
   2510     def error(self, message):

SystemExit: 2

At first removed unnecessary parts on python 3 (version 3.8.8) like sys.setdefaultencoding() function.
Now, I'm not sure the error is up to _sys.exit(status) in the lib.
Suggestions?

Possibly duplicate, related, or helpful SystemExit: 2 error when calling parse_args() within ipython
